# Html : JSON To different group of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

Let's say, I have a JS Object. That looks like:

```
var basicRadioStructure = 
{
  4 : "Option 1" 
  5 : "Option 2"
  6 : "Option 3"
};
```

Let's say, I have an array which is:

```
var radioValuesForEachGroup = [4,5,6];
```

In this case, **the number of radio button group is the size of array** where in each group:

- **4 means** Option 1 is checked
- **5 means** Option 2 is checked
- **6 means** Option 3 is checked

as per the value defined in **basicRadioStructure** Object. What I want is to traverse the array radioValuesForEachGroup and make radio buttons like this:

When traversing radioValuesForEachGroup array and the value is 4 then it should generate this kind of radio group **Where Option 1 is checked:**

```
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="4" checked> Option 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="5"> Option 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="6"> Option 3
```

**When value = 5, Option 2 should be checked :**

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="4" > Option 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="5" checked> Option 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="6"> Option 3
```

**When value = 6, Option 3 should be checked :**

```
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="4" > Option 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="5"> Option 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="6" checked> Option 3
```

After generating all these radio groups from JavaScript/jQuery, I want to display them in to this div below:

```
<div id="Radios">
</div>
```

How should I approach to solve this problem?

Comment: so you need to create the options to select on basis of array's data

Comment: @AhmedAli exactly

Comment: So one array produce multiple radio boxes. please tell me about your second array

Comment: @AhmedAli The radio groups are repeated; You can see the difference is the name attribute of each radio group and based on the value in second array the checked attribute is changing in each group.

Comment: Answered @Shunjid, try to change values in `ValForGroup` but don't enter duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work.

```js
var options = {
  "4" : "Option 1",
  "5" : "Option 2",
  "6" : "Option 3"
};
var ValForGroup = ["4","5","6"];
var l = Object.keys(options).length;
Object.keys(options).forEach(function (item) {
  for(var a =0;a<l;a++){
    if(ValForGroup[a] == item)
    {   
      $("body").append("<input type='radio' name='group"+item+"' value='"+options[item]+"' checked>"+options[item]);
     
    }
    else{
      $("body").append("<input type='radio' name='group"+item+"' value='"+options[item]+"' >"+options[item]);
    }
}
$("body").append("<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Shukria, Bhaijaan.

Comment: Kuch Masla Nahi Bhaijaan